# Implementing https to administrative console

Tags: kaa

I wanted to implement https for the administrative console of Kaa.Is there a way of doing this so that the login information passed through the administrative console can be encrypted

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. For this you can configure another server with SSL as a reverse proxy for Kaa. You can use a web server like Nginx.
For more details about installation and configuration instruction described above, use [How To Create an SSL Certificate on Nginx for Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04) and [How To Configure Nginx with SSL as a Reverse Proxy for Jenkins](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) guides.

1. Update your package lists and install Nginx:

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install nginx
> ```

2. Install openssl to create an SSL certificate:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install openssl
> ```

3. Create a a self-signed SSL certificate in the /etc/nginx/ directory:

> ```
> sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/cert.key -out /etc/nginx/cert.crt
> ```

4. Edit the default Nginx configuration file.

> ```
> sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
> ```

You can replace the existing configuration file.

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
> }
>
> server {
>
>     listen 8085;
>     server_name 192.168.x.x;
>
>     ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
>     ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;
>
>     ssl on;
>     ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
>     ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
>     ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
>     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
>
>     access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
>
>     location / {
>
>       proxy_set_header        Host $host;
>       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>
>       # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
>       proxy_pass          http://192.168.x.x:8080;
>       proxy_read_timeout  90;
>
>       proxy_redirect      http://192.168.x.x:8080 https://192.168.x.x;
>     }
>   }
> ```

Where, 
listen 8085; - new port instead of 8080 to access administrative console (you can use default 443 port).

Instead of 192.168.x.x enter your IP address.

5. Restart Nginx:

> sudo service nginx restart

6. Log in to the Kaa administrative console:

> https://192.168.x.x:8085/